# Uncheck a Checkbox using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a page with a list of check boxes, when a check box is checked I am updating the number of check boxes selected in side a p tag. This is all working.

The problem I have is when the user selects more than 5 checkboxes I want to use Jquery to unselect it.

This is what I have so far, the first if else works but the first part of the if doe

```
 $("input").click(function () {

        if ($("input:checked").size() > 5) {
            this.attr('checked', false) // Unchecks it
        }
        else {
            $("#numberOfSelectedOptions").html("Selected: " + $("input:checked").size());
        }

    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the html as well?

Comment: `this.attr('checked', false)` This will not work!!

Comment: You should be using `length` and not `size()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you should use the `change` event when dealing with checkboxes so that it caters for users who navigate via the keyboard only. Secondly, if the number of selected checkboxes is already 5 or greater you can stop the selection of the current checkbox by using `preventDefault()`. Try this:

```
$("input").change(function (e) {
    var $inputs = $('input:checked');
    if ($inputs.length > 5 && this.checked) {
        this.checked = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $("#numberOfSelectedOptions").html("Selected: " + $inputs.length);
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfL3ys5a/)

Note I restricted the fiddle to 2 selections so that it's easier to test.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but "click" fires when the spacebar is used to check a box.

Comment: I believe that is the behaviour in newer browsers, but you should still use `change()` to ensure compatibility on all.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that, gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

You need this `$(this).prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 1):

You should be saying

```
$(this).attr('checked', false)
```

instead of

```
this.attr('checked', false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this `$(this).prop('checked', false);`

Also `this` is a javascript object, if you want to use jquery you should prefer  `$(this)`.